# What Ubuntu packages are still affected by gnutls bug CVE-2014-0092?

Tags: tls, linux

Right now the internet is abuzz with [news](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/03/critical-crypto-bug-leaves-linux-hundreds-of-apps-open-to-eavesdropping/) about a severe  [breach](http://www.gnutls.org/security.html#GNUTLS-SA-2014-2) in GnuTLS.

An update to the relevant GnuTLS packages has already been released. But I am worried whether some packages might have had GnuTLS compiled directly into them, instead of dynamically linking to them.

Would like to know the likelihood of this- If any of you are aware of any such packages, please share them.

Comment: Hi nedR - while this question is about security, I feel you may get better answers on AskUbuntu - do you want me to migrate this question over for you?

Comment: @RoryAlsop: Thanks for asking before moderating :) I considered this too.. but I thought that the IT Security group were in a better position to answer this question than AskUbuntu. If you feel this really belongs in AskUbuntu, please migrate it. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll ask some of the regulars in [chat] - I just have a feeling that you'll need folks with the wider view of Ubuntu packages. Lemme check and get back to you shortly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Canonical's CVE tracker](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0092.html) `gnutls26` package is totally patched, while `gnutls28` on Precise (12.04) and Saucy (13.10) are still affected, and others versions are not affected. There aren't any bugs related to fix these versions [in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/bugs/cve/CVE-2014-0092) either, so, unless your are using 12.04 or 13.10 is safe to say that you are not affected by this bug.

Answer (score -1):

nedR, after viewing the GnuTLS site, I found that any versions prior to version 3.2.12 or 3.2.22 are still vulnerable. The Ubuntu packages using GnuTLS 28 are mostly still affected. That is, packages 12.04, 12.10, 13.10, and 14.04. Glad to be of assistance!